# Can't figure out whats wrong Installed LETSENCRYPT, NGINX, PHP & MYSQL on UBUNTU

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, nginx, lets-encrypt

I get 404 without https and ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED with https

I think it has to do something with permissions as before installing php and mysql it worked fine but after installing them it just wont work.

Domain `aleealamm.com`
IP `15.185.127.174`

etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {


    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;


    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;


    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

etc/nginx/sites-available/aleealamm.com

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name aleealamm.com www.aleealamm.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl default_server;

  # enables SSLv3/TLSv1, but not SSLv2 which is weak and should no longer be used.
  ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
  
  # disables all weak ciphers
  ssl_ciphers ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM;

  server_name www.aleealamm.com aleealamm.com;

  ## Access and error logs.
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log info;

  ## Keep alive timeout set to a greater value for SSL/TLS.
  keepalive_timeout 75 75;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/aleealamm.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/aleealamm.com.key;
  ssl_session_timeout  5m;

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=7200";
  
  root /var/www/aleealamm.com/;
  index index.php;
}
```

error.log

```
2020/06/22 17:58:46 [notice] 3310#3310: signal process started
2020/06/22 18:00:26 [notice] 3553#3553: signal process started
2020/06/22 18:00:32 [notice] 3556#3556: signal process started
2020/06/22 18:00:35 [notice] 3559#3559: signal process started
2020/06/22 18:00:51 [notice] 3562#3562: signal process started
2020/06/22 18:01:21 [notice] 3573#3573: signal process started
2020/06/22 18:01:26 [notice] 3576#3576: signal process started
2020/06/22 18:01:30 [notice] 3579#3579: signal process started
2020/06/22 18:10:14 [error] 3580#3580: *23 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "aleealamm.com"
2020/06/22 18:12:13 [error] 3580#3580: *25 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "aleealamm.com"
2020/06/22 18:12:18 [error] 3580#3580: *25 directory index of "/var/www/html/install/" is forbidden, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET /install/ HTTP/1.1", host: "aleealamm.com"
2020/06/22 18:13:39 [error] 3580#3580: *27 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 178.32.104.221, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "firmaflowers.com"
2020/06/22 18:13:39 [error] 3580#3580: *27 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 178.32.104.221, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "firmaflowers.com"
2020/06/22 18:13:39 [error] 3580#3580: *27 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 178.32.104.221, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "firmaflowers.com"
2020/06/22 18:14:34 [error] 3580#3580: *29 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 73.253.45.29, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "15.185.127.174"
2020/06/22 18:18:26 [warn] 11935#11935: conflicting server name "aleealamm.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2020/06/22 18:21:12 [notice] 11942#11942: signal process started
2020/06/22 18:22:06 [warn] 11950#11950: conflicting server name "aleealamm.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2020/06/22 18:22:06 [notice] 11950#11950: signal process started
2020/06/22 18:25:00 [error] 11951#11951: *38 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66" while reading response header from upstream, client: 85.215.2.227, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET /install/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "www.aleealamm.com"
2020/06/22 18:25:34 [warn] 11959#11959: conflicting server name "aleealamm.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2020/06/22 18:26:49 [notice] 11966#11966: signal process started
2020/06/22 18:26:51 [error] 11967#11967: *41 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66" while reading response header from upstream, client: 101.21.146.63, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET /install/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "www.aleealamm.com"
2020/06/22 18:27:52 [notice] 12148#12148: signal process started
2020/06/22 18:28:51 [error] 863#863: *2 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66" while reading response header from upstream, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET /install/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "ec2-15-185-127-174.me-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com"
2020/06/22 18:29:02 [error] 863#863: *2 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66" while reading response header from upstream, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET /install/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "ec2-15-185-127-174.me-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com"
2020/06/22 18:29:45 [error] 863#863: *7 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66" while reading response header from upstream, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET /install/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "aleealamm.com"
2020/06/22 18:29:45 [error] 863#863: *10 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66" while reading response header from upstream, client: 107.170.96.6, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET /install/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "aleealamm.com", referrer: "15.185.127.174"
2020/06/22 18:32:56 [error] 863#863: *12 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66" while reading response header from upstream, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET /install/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "aleealamm.com"
2020/06/22 18:33:17 [error] 863#863: *14 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66" while reading response header from upstream, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET /install/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "15.185.127.174"
2020/06/22 18:33:18 [error] 863#863: *19 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66" while reading response header from upstream, client: 159.203.42.143, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET /install/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "15.185.127.174", referrer: "15.185.127.174"
2020/06/22 18:36:49 [crit] 863#863: *22 stat() "/var/www/html/install/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET /install/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "15.185.127.174"
2020/06/22 18:36:51 [crit] 863#863: *23 stat() "/var/www/html/install/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET /install/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "aleealamm.com"
2020/06/22 18:38:06 [crit] 863#863: *24 stat() "/var/www/html/install/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET /install/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "aleealamm.com"
2020/06/22 18:41:36 [error] 863#863: *25 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66" while reading response header from upstream, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET /install/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "15.185.127.174"
2020/06/22 18:41:38 [error] 863#863: *25 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66" while reading response header from upstream, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET /install/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "15.185.127.174"
2020/06/22 18:41:38 [error] 863#863: *25 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66" while reading response header from upstream, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET /install/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "15.185.127.174"
2020/06/22 18:41:39 [error] 863#863: *25 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66" while reading response header from upstream, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET /install/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "15.185.127.174"
2020/06/22 18:41:39 [error] 863#863: *25 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66" while reading response header from upstream, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET /install/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "15.185.127.174"
2020/06/22 18:41:39 [error] 863#863: *25 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66" while reading response header from upstream, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET /install/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "15.185.127.174"
2020/06/22 18:41:46 [error] 863#863: *32 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66" while reading response header from upstream, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET /install/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "aleealamm.com"
2020/06/22 18:45:19 [error] 863#863: *34 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66" while reading response header from upstream, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET /install/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "www.aleealamm.com"
2020/06/22 18:45:20 [error] 863#863: *36 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66" while reading response header from upstream, client: 159.203.42.143, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET /install/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "www.aleealamm.com", referrer: "15.185.127.174"
2020/06/22 18:45:23 [error] 863#863: *34 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/../react/promise/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/system/storage/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66" while reading response header from upstream, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET /install/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "www.aleealamm.com"
2020/06/22 18:45:26 [error] 863#863: *34 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.aleealamm.com"
2020/06/22 18:45:28 [error] 863#863: *34 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.aleealamm.com"
2020/06/22 18:45:28 [error] 863#863: *34 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.aleealamm.com"
2020/06/22 18:45:28 [error] 863#863: *34 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.aleealamm.com"
2020/06/22 18:49:57 [error] 1619#1619: *1 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 193.112.43.115, server: aleealamm.com, request: "HEAD /?key=www.hubeiymch.cn HTTP/1.1", host: "www.firmaflowers.com"
2020/06/22 18:50:26 [notice] 1635#1635: signal process started
2020/06/22 18:50:29 [notice] 1639#1639: signal process started
2020/06/22 18:57:15 [error] 1640#1640: *2 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 203.195.136.130, server: aleealamm.com, request: "HEAD /?q=www.hunanymcd.cn HTTP/1.1", host: "www.firmaflowers.com"
2020/06/22 19:02:47 [error] 1640#1640: *4 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.aleealamm.com"
2020/06/22 19:02:48 [error] 1640#1640: *4 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.aleealamm.com"
2020/06/22 19:02:48 [error] 1640#1640: *4 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.aleealamm.com"
2020/06/22 19:02:48 [error] 1640#1640: *4 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.aleealamm.com"
2020/06/22 19:02:49 [error] 1640#1640: *4 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 77.69.206.9, server: aleealamm.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.aleealamm.com"
```

Comment: I would start by checking the permissions of `/var/www/html/`.

Comment: Hello Dirk, what should be the permission for /var/www/html? Its 755 currently.

Comment: 755 is fine. Did you check for the owner too? 'www-data` should be the owner and my guess is another user is owning this directory.